# Multidict generation using for loop in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a problem with python that is I want to generate a multidict like the one below, using a for loop. Numbers are generated randomly and if the two elements are the same, the value if 0.

```
arcs, capacity = multidict({
  (0, 0): 0,

  (0, 1): 80,

  (0, 2): 11,

  (1, 0): 15,

  (1, 1): 0,

  (1, 2): 120

  (2, 0): 103,

  (2, 1): 3,

  (2, 2): 0 })
```

So far I coded this one:

```
arcs = {}

for i in range(N):

    for j in range(N):

        arcs[i,j]=(random.randint(1,101))
```

But it's nothing like the one I need.
Can anyone help me on how to code the for loop for this problem?
Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: `arcs[(i,j)]=(random.randint(1,101)) if i != j else 0`

Comment: What is `multidict`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP want to create a multidict as in http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/examples/netflow_py.html

Goal is to generate a dictionary object that can be taken as the input of  `multidict`, an api in the **gurobi** software. The needed input has a shape like

```
{ (0, 0): 0,    
  (0, 1): 80,    
  (0, 2): 11,    
  (1, 0): 15,
  (1, 1): 0,    
  (1, 2): 120    
  (2, 0): 103,
  (2, 1): 3, 
  (2, 2): 0 }
```

Method 1: for loop and dictionary

```
from gurobi import multidict
multidict_input = {}

for i in range(N):    
    for j in range(N):    
        multidict_input[i,j] = random.randint(1,101) if i != j else 0

arcs, capacity = multidict(multidict_input)  # feed it into multidict
```

Method 2: (dictionary comprehension)

```
multidict_input = dict()
multidict_input = {(a,b): random.randint(1,101) if a != b else 0 
                   for a in range(N) for b in range(N)}
arcs, capacities = multidict(multidict_input)
```

Comment: Similar to the previous answer, I really thank you for answering.
The problem that I am having is that I need to have both arcs and capacities to use later in gurobi.
So arcs should be in this format:
(0,0)
(0,1)
(0,2)
(1,0)
and so on and capacities as separate numbers.
Using this code, I only have one entity that is my_dict so I do not know how to assign each pair of numbers to arcs and their corresponding number to capacity for that arc.

Comment: @AZ Sorry. I do not fully understand becaue I am not familiar with gurobi. So now you need two things, arcs and capacities. is capacity referred to random.randin(1, 101)? arcs refer to the tuples>

Comment: @AZ if you want to loop over my_dict, use `for arc, capacity in my_dict.items():...` Here, we are storing the each arc (i, j) as the key in the dictionary and the corresponding value is the capacity.

Comment: Hi again, That is true. arcs are pairs of numbers and capacities are the random numbers. How can I define items? Should I define or prealocate a value to arcs and items first?
I'm sorry if my questions are elementary but I'm very new to python

Comment: This is the link to gurobi-python code. 
http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/examples/netflow_py.html
I need to generate the arc, capacity randomly for a given specific number of arcs and their corresponding capacity.

Comment: @AZ the `arcs` in my code will store `i, j` as the key, or arc in your problem, and a random number, the capacity, will be the value of the dictionary. This should already be what you want. A dictionary is a collection of key-value pairs that you can access the value by a key. If you want keys, or arcs, separately, you can call arcs.keys(). Similarly, if you want capacities alone, call arcs.values().

Comment: First, you need to know what are arcs and what is capacities.  Can you print out the `arcs` and `capacities` in the example posted to check what kind of data you really want? Also, this problem is gurobi specific and thus, you need to have a tag about that to attract people who know it to help you.

Comment: @AZ My current understanding is that the `arcs` in the example corresponds to `arcs.keys()` in my code. `arcs` are a list of possible edges. `capacities` corresponds to `arcs` here.

Comment: @AZ Did I solve your problem? If so, would you consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark?

Comment: Thank you so much Tai for the great help!

Comment: @AZ Pleasure :P

Comment: @AZ why you accept another person's answer? by accident?

Comment: Hi Tai. I accepted your answer because it solved the problem. Shouldn’t have I done that?

Comment: @AZ you changed... you accept other people's answer now. See the check mark is now on other people's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your keys are distinct, you won't really need to create a `multidict`. Going off what you described, you can achieve this in one line with an unwieldy dictionary comprehension or with nested for loops.

```
import random

def create_multi_dict_comprehension(n, random_bound=100):
    return {k : 0 if k[0] == k[1] else v for k in [(x,y) for x in range(n + 1) for y in range(n + 1)] for v in [random.randint(1, random_bound) for _ in range(n ** 2)]}


def create_multi_dict(n, random_bound=100):
    my_dict = {}
    for i in range(n+1):
        for j in range(n+1):
            my_dict[(i,j)] = 0 if i==j else random.randint(1,random_bound)
    return my_dict


print(create_multi_dict(2))
# {(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 91, (0, 2): 24, (1, 0): 77, (1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 39, (2, 0): 94, (2, 1): 60, (2, 2): 0}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.
The problem that I am having is that I need to have both arcs and capacities to use later in gurobi.
So arcs should be in this format:
(0,0)
(0,1)
(0,2)
(1,0)
and so on and capacities as separate numbers.
Using this code, I only have one entity that is my_dict so I do not know how to assign each pair of numbers to arcs and their corresponding number to capacity for that arc.